# Implementing a Canvas in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have been trying to learn to using PyQt5.

I want to implement a canvas below the "Menu Bar"

```py
class gui(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(gui, self).__init__(parent)
        self.createTopLayout()
        self.painter = canvas(self)
        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(self.topLayout, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.painter, 1, 0, 6, 2)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def createTopLayout(self):
        self.topLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        button1 = QPushButton("b1")
        button2 = QPushButton("b2")
        button3 = QPushButton("b3")
        styleComboBox = QComboBox()
        styleComboBox.addItems(QStyleFactory.keys())
        styleLabel = QLabel("&Style:")
        styleLabel.setBuddy(styleComboBox)
        self.topLayout.addWidget(styleLabel)
        self.topLayout.addWidget(styleComboBox)
        self.topLayout.addStretch(1)
        self.topLayout.addWidget(button1)
        self.topLayout.addWidget(button2)
        self.topLayout.addWidget(button3)
```

Where my canvas is defined as

```py
class canvas(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(canvas, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 700)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        cir = circle() #circle class creates a circle with random center and radius both between 0 to 100
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 1, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawEllipse(self, cir.center.x, cir.center.y, cir.radius, cir.radius)
```

but for me canvas doesnt render at all let alone the ellipse.

Comment: Whats is circle?

Comment: i believe i added a comment explaining that... #circle class creates a circle with random center and radius both between 0 to 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use QMainWindow as a canvas, instead use a QWidget. On the other hand setGeometry will not work if you use layout since the latter handles the geometry, instead it establishes a fixed size and adequate margins. On the other hand it is recommended that the name of the classes begin with capital letters, considering the above the solution is:

```
class Canvas(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Canvas, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(1000, 700)
        self.setContentsMargins(100, 100, 100, 100)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        # ...
```

Comment: I just figured out that paintEvent only happens on event, how can i set a draw function to draw a circle as necessary?

Comment: @Blaine You have to call the canvas `update()` method, although I think you are reinventing the wheel: Use QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene and its items.

Comment: you saved my life! I am wondering how i can extend addEllipse to add a circle with text at the center, as addText takes no positional parameters.